# videoCapture open works for webcam but not for ip camera

Tags: java, opencv

I want to get images/video from tp link ip camera, specifically TL-SC3130G, but cannot get video from it using VideoCapture opencv java. The code below works fine for the webcam. How can I access a camera connected to the same router.

```
VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture();
boolean check=camera.open("rtsp://192.168.0.101:554/video.mp4");
if(!check)
{
    System.out.println(" Error cannot open");

}
```

the ouput is Error cannot open

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
boolean check=camera.open("rtsp://192.168.0.101:554/video?x.mjpeg");
```